# How can I move the start point of the input?

Tags: html, css

I made a login form and I put an icon next to each input. But those icons are overlapping the text zone. How can I make the input start next to the icon.

[image]

I tried in CSS with a text-align: center; but it's not what I was expecting. The text align is a text format not a text placement.

```css
.fa-solid.fa-user {
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
    right: 250px;
    top: 2px;
}

.fa-solid.fa-lock {
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
    right: 250px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="centered">
  <div id="form">
    <h2>Connexion</h2>
    <form>
      <p>Nom d'utilisateur</p>
      <p><input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required /><span><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span></p>
      <p>Mot de passe</p>
      <p><input type="password" name="password" id="pw" placeholder="Mot de passe" required /><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name="login" value="S'enregistrer" required /></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: If you want to preserve your padding you could use `text-indent` instead. `#username, #pw {text-indent:2em;}`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this issue is utilizing the padding characteristic of the input box. If you set the padding-left of each input box equal to the size of the icon, it should account for the space necessary.

```css
input {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="centered">
  <div id="form">
    <h2>Connexion</h2>
    <form>
      <p>Nom d'utilisateur</p>
      <p><input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required /><span><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span></p>
      <p>Mot de passe</p>
      <p><input type="password" name="password" id="pw" placeholder="Mot de passe" required /><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name="login" value="S'enregistrer" required /></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used 20px just to display the idea, but you can replace that with whatever size value will allow the icons to fit.

Comment: I'd use `em` or `ch` units on this so that it responds to potential resizing.

Comment: @Wolfeur that's definitely a good idea. I just did px to get the point across but responsiveness is always very important.

Answer (score 0):

set the div as position:relative and then u can give left:20px and top:10px etc... to control the input starting

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution. Please do not write in textspeak on SO. 'u' isn't a word.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to do this, is by using `padding` on the input. If you only want to change the space in the beggining, use `padding-left` but you can add more space in other places.

```css
.fa-solid.fa-user {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
  right: 250px;
  top: 2px;
}

.fa-solid.fa-lock {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
  right: 250px;
  top: 2px;
}

#username,
#pw {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="centered">
  <div id="form">
    <h2>Connexion</h2>
    <form>
      <p>Nom d'utilisateur</p>
      <p><input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required /><span><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span></p>
      <p>Mot de passe</p>
      <p><input type="password" name="password" id="pw" placeholder="Mot de passe" required /><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name="login" value="S'enregistrer" required /></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```